# Shorter version of now()

Tags: python, datetime

I want to get the current date time in a certain format. Is there anything shorter than this.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
'2013-03-28 08:29:41'
```

Comment: Why? Are you writing code golf?

Comment: you can create a function instead of calling this every time

Comment: Voting to Close it as its off topic. Suitable for http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Wouldn't say off topic, it's more about coding style, but too localised.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there isn't. But you don't have to always repeat the entire invocation. For example:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now
>>> now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
'2013-03-28 08:29:41'
```

If you always want the same format, you could wrap that, too:

```
import datetime
def now_string():
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Then just store that in a string (or write a function).

Answer (score 4):

Just put it in a function somewhere

```
import datetime
def my_now():
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

You can make it more flexible with some optional arguments

```
import datetime
def my_now(the_time=None, fmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'):
    if the_time is None:
        the_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    return the_time.strftime(fmt)
```

Answer (score 2):

If that's all you want, so be it. But please don't blame me for such a hackish code :-)

```
>>> import datetime
>>> str(datetime.datetime.now())[:19]
'2013-03-28 15:57:31'
```

No of characters 32 :-)

Comment: `str(datetime.datetime.now()).split('.')[0]` is 42...   +1

Answer (score 0):

As your format string is close to the default format, you only have to get rid of the microseconds:

```
import datetime
str(datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond = 0))
```